# Facebook Like And Twitter Tweet Load Slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter

I have put a facebook like, facebook send, and twitter tweet button 10 times on my web page (1 for each article in my thread), but yet the page loads very slowly. Right now the site is just running on my local XAMPP stack but when I comment out those widgets, the page loads instantaneously. Otherwise it takes like 10 seconds to load.

Comment: Great then please read the link I posted above and ... Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838254/lots-of-xfbml-facebook-like-buttons-are-slow/6847489#6847489

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the code to make sure you are applying it correctly, but I've experienced similar symptoms before.  The way I would render it is by having the associated external Javascript files just before your `</body>` tag and not in your head.  If the connection to the external host is slow, it can cause parallisation issues so you want to load it last.

Comment: hey yeah this works!  I was doing 2 things wrong. 1) When looping through my 10 articles, i mistakenly added the script part of the widgets in each time and 2) i added the scripts now just once at the bottom of my footer. Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem... I am using FBML to load the buttons, and looking the requests made via the net tab in firebug, it's making the *same* requests for *every* button... so it's using like 100 requests extra downloading exactly the same resource over and over again... I already put my scripts at the end of the body tag, so at least I can see the page loaded, but it still slows down the page up to 10s from a page that takes 0.5s to load completely... and when I'm seeing the page still loading the like buttons one by one, I would still think the page isn't fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening all over the web lately. I'll see a slow-loading page and sure enough at the bottom there's a note that facebook or twitter is still loading.

The solution I found was an extension that shows the FB, Twitter buttons but doesn't actually load them unless you click the button. That way your page loads quickly and if FB or Twitter is slow that's their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Sharrre](http://sharrre.com) for social sharing buttons. I activate it on mouseover so nothing is loaded until the user actually needs it. Hard to get it faster than this. It also supports a few other networks.

I don't load social sharing buttons directly anymore and only do it when there is no other option. Those things are horrible for loading times specially if used multiple times on the same page.

Comment: Does it load fast enough to actually be available if a user clicks on it immediately? What about the number of likes/tweets, won't those not be visible until they mouse-over? What about people who navigate between links using tab (I'm thinking accessibility). Touch screen tablets or mobile devices?